# VS Code not tracking files and won't open new tabs

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I was working on a project, was able to click on a file in the tree to open it in a new tab, and was using Gulp Watch to see my changes in real-time. Suddenly, two of my files turned green in the file tree, and have a capital "U" next to them. Also, whenever I click on a file in the tree, instead of opening in a new tab it replaces whichever tab I currently have active. This is beyond annoying!

Did I hit the wrong button or something? What's going on?!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are experiencing standard VSCode features. If you're inside a Git repo, VSCode highlights modified files showing their changes. In this case, green highlighted files with a U would indicate you have Untracked files/changes.

VSCode also enables previews by default. Meaning when you single click a file, it will open a preview window until you either double click it, or make a change in it. To turn off this behavior, change this vscode setting like so:

```
{ "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false }
```